# Hartree-Fock Hamiltonian and higher-order terms

Tags: second-quantization, wick-theorem, mean-field-theory

I'm diving into Hartree-Fock methods, and I'm confused on why the Hartree-Fock Hamiltonian reduces into a single particle Hamiltonian.

When applying Wick's theorem to the Fermi Sea vacuum, we use the particle-hole picture which transforms the Hamiltonian into

$$
H = \sum_i h_{ii} + \sum_{ij} \frac{1}{2} \left[ \langle ij \rVert V \rVert ij \rangle - \langle ij \rVert V \rVert ji \rangle \right] + \sum_{pq} \left[ h_{pq} + \sum_i \left[ \langle pi \rVert V \rVert qi \rangle - \langle pi \rVert V \rVert iq \rangle \right] \right] : c_p^\dagger c_q : + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{pqrs} \langle pq \rVert V \rVert rs \rangle : c_p^\dagger c_q^\dagger c_s c_r:.
$$

where $ : :$ denotes normal ordering in the particle-hole picture in a Fermi sea vacuum.

The first term is the Hartree-Fock energy, which we want to minimize. The second term, which is the Fock matrix, gives the single particle/hole excitations. Variational principle tells us that the self-consistency method will involve diagonalizing the Fock Matrix, so we can expect a full SCF will give a diagonal one-particle term corresponding to the single quasiparticle energy $\varepsilon_p \delta_{pq}$.

The typical literature for Hartree-Fock states that applying mean field to the two-body interaction we reduced the Hamiltonian to a diagonal single particle Hamiltonian, which is true if we look until this order. e.g., http://felix.physics.sunysb.edu/%7Eallen/555-07/Mean-field-theory.pdf. However, I do not understand why are we ignoring the two-particle normal ordered interaction (third term).

Am I missing something in my understanding? Any help on this will be appreciated!

Comment: Hartree-Fock is an approximation where you neglect the electron "correlations."  This means you have an effective single-particle theory, but the theory has to be "self-consistent." I.e., you have to construct the mean-field part of the the hamiltonian from the orbitals, but then you solve for the orbitals using the hamiltonian... but that means you have a new hamiltonian, so you repeat the process until the orbitals stop changing (this is the "self-consistent" part.) Again, it is just an approximation, where, you are right, the true electron-electron interaction in all its glory is ignored